# Fragmenting documents

Tags: dms

We are writing documentation for several of our software applications. Those documentation documents share some common content fragments (eg corporate profile, etc.).

I need to find some decent DMS that would allow us to manage the fragments of the documentation (the common parts and the product-specific or document-specific parts) and assemble documents from them. We'll also need to handle versioning.

Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is solving the same problem, I solved it with MadCap Flare in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Have to tried writing your documentation in LaTex. In this tool you can write simple scripts or create reusable components, which you can use in other documents too.

[Here](http://latex-project.org/guides/) is the link to get more information.